# Listview items not updating wpf vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

I'm creating an application where we open a new window that has options to choose from in a listview, we extract one of the items in the listview and pass it on to another listview on a different window. I can populate the listview on the main window and can verify that the items are getting added during debug with an .items.count but they aren't getting added realtime. If I do a .show to open another instance of the window I see the items there but since I'm not planning on closing the main window out, how do you 'refresh' the listview to show the options that are clearly there?

I've read that if the listview is binded to a table, you can just re-bind the data to refresh it but since this listview isn't binded to anything and is just adding items to it with the .add function, I'm not sure how to 'refresh' it to show the values.

Edit:
Here is my code currently,

```
Public Class ObservableColl

    Public Structure Steps
        Private _Steps As List(Of String)
        Property Steps() As List(Of String)
            Get
                Return _Steps
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As List(Of String))
                _Steps = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Structure

    Dim songs As New ObservableCollection(Of Steps)

End Class


 Private Sub CloseForm()
        Dim stepArr As String() = Split(sCommon.presetSteps, ",")
        Dim entries As New List(Of String)

        For i = 0 To stepArr.Count - 1
            entries.Add(stepArr(i))
        Next

        sCommon.form1.entries.Add(New Steps With {.Steps = entries}) 'Add list entries to the observableCollection
        sCommon.form1.lvwCurrentSteps.DataContext = entries 'Assign the DataContext property to the observableCollection

        If Not PresetList Is Nothing Then 
            Me.Close() 'Close this form and focus returns to the main window
        End If

    End Sub

<ListView Margin="49,23,0,33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="230" Name="lvwCurrentSteps" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="myGridView">
                    <GridViewColumn Width="220" Header="Steps to run"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Steps}">
                    </GridViewColumn>                                    
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I can validate that there are items in the listview with this method but the listview doesn't 'refresh' with these values when focus returns to the original window.

```
?sCommon.form1.lvwCurrentSteps.Items.Count
3
```

Comment: I'm sorry can't say what is causing your issue, but why not bind the `Listview` to a collection and instead add items to that collection? I try to avoid directly manipulating WPF controls in code-behind, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from just this snippet but it looks like your logic is backwards in these two lines:

```
sCommon.form1.entries.Add(New Steps With {.Steps = entries}) 'Add list entries to the observableCollection
sCommon.form1.lvwCurrentSteps.DataContext = entries 'Assign the DataContext property to the observableCollection
```

I would expect that the `DataContext` you would want to use would be the collection you just added to, not the local variable that was what you added (which is a `List Of String` and so has no `Steps` property to support your `DisplayMemberBinding`). It also seems a little strange the way that the `ObservableColl` class is set up, with an `ObservableCollection` of objects containing a `List`.

I'm not sure what's happening with the count but you should validate that your basic logic is really doing what you mean it to.